# Better way to implement Trie Data Structure in Rust

Tags: pointers, rust, reference

Recently I teaching myself Rust, and tried to code Trie Data Structure.
I've already coded Trie in C++ as below.

```cpp
struct node_t
{
    bool is_end = false;
    std::vector<std::pair<char, node_t>> children;

    void push(std::string str)
    {
        node_t* curr = this;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        {
            char curr_char = str[i];
            std::vector<std::pair<char, node_t>>::iterator iter = std::find_if(curr->children.begin(), curr->children.end(), [&](std::pair<char, node_t>& e) { return e.first == curr_char; });

            curr = iter != curr->children.end() ?
                   &iter->second :
                   (curr->children.push_back(std::make_pair(curr_char, node_t{ false, std::vector<std::pair<char, node_t>>() })), &(curr->children.end() - 1)->second);

        }

        curr->is_end = true;
    }

    bool has(std::string str)
    {
        node_t* curr = this;

        for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        {
            char curr_char = str[i];
            std::vector<std::pair<char, node_t>>::iterator iter = std::find_if(curr->children.begin(), curr->children.end(), [&](std::pair<char, node_t>& e) { return e.first == curr_char; });

            if (iter == curr->children.end())
                return false;

            curr = &iter->second;
        }

        return curr->is_end;
    }
};
```

As you can see, function "push" and "has" uses its own reference variable "self" as a pointer named "curr".
And the pointer "curr" keep chainging while go through the given string named "str".

If next character is in the children vector "curr" is changed to that child.
Else, "curr" is changed to new child with new character, which pushed newly.

I wrote code in Rust similarly like below.

```rust
fn push(&mut self, string: &str) {
    let mut curr = self;

    for c in string.chars() {
        curr = match curr.children.iter_mut().find(|e| e.0 == c) {
            Some(e) => &mut e.1,
            None => {
                curr.children.push((c, Node { is_end: false, children: Vec::new() }));
                &mut curr.children.last_mut().unwrap().1
            }
        }
    }

    curr.is_end = true;
}
```

Code above uses technic as C++ code uses.
But, here's the catch.

"curr" pointer in C++ is used to in two ways.

First, to keep track of the given string, which means "curr" itself keeps changing so that "curr" must be mut variable.
Second, to push a new character in the given string, which means "curr" must reference mut variable.

Since we have to reasons "curr" to be mut and &mut, and need to use "curr" with mut twice complier complains about it.

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `curr.children` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> C:\Users\first\Developments\Temp\trie.rs:44:17
   |
41 |         curr = match curr.children.iter_mut().find(|e| e.0 == c) {
   |                      ------------------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
...
44 |                 curr.children.push((c, Node { is_end: false, children: Vec::new() }));
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                 first borrow later used here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `curr.children` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> C:\Users\first\Developments\Temp\trie.rs:45:22
   |
41 |         curr = match curr.children.iter_mut().find(|e| e.0 == c) {
   |                      ------------------------ first mutable borrow occurs here
...
45 |                 &mut curr.children.last_mut().unwrap().1
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                      first borrow later used here

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 1 warning emitted
```

The question is: Is there any ways to resolve this problem so that the code it simillar to as C++ code above? Or if I should come up with a brand new code, what it be looks like?

And if question is not valid or explatations with "curr" is not correct please correct me.

Comment: the best way to do that in rust is to not do it. https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/ please read the warning of author about this being NOT A GOOD WAY to learn rust.

Comment: I see raw pointers in your C++ code. To get the Rust experience, try rewriting your C++ trie using only `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Stargateur A trie doesn't need a parent pointer, and so it is a perfect fit for Rust.

Comment: @Chris Rust has references, which are not like `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman what ? a tree ? a linked list is a tree that only have one branch, so a tree need parent like linked list since they are both the same thing in nature.

Comment: @Stargateur Not all trees need parent pointers.

Comment: doesn't change you have child pointer so, it's a linked list as least in this question I see code that look like pointer code of list. call it whatever you want you will still have the same problem implementing this in rust

Comment: @Stargateur As long as you don't have parent pointers, forming a tree structure and not a graph (including singly linked list), it is very easy to implement the datastructure in Rust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is correct and should've been accepted. The fact it is not is because of a known flaw of the borrow checker (it is accepted with the next-gen [Polonius](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius) borrow checker).

The problem is that the borrow checker thinks the reference from the `Some` case is active in the `None` case, even though it is not. The solution is to not keep a reference, for example using [`position()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.position):

```rust
pub fn push(&mut self, string: &str) {
    let mut curr = self;

    for c in string.chars() {
        curr = match curr.children.iter_mut().position(|e| e.0 == c) {
            Some(idx) => &mut curr.children[idx].1,
            None => {
                curr.children.push((
                    c,
                    Node {
                        is_end: false,
                        children: Vec::new(),
                    },
                ));
                &mut curr.children.last_mut().unwrap().1
            }
        }
    }

    curr.is_end = true;
}
```